# How to use custom keyboard shortcuts within CKeditor with jQuery?

Tags: jquery, keyboard-shortcuts, ckeditor

I have replaced the textarea my users use to edit content with CKeditor. Before this change, users were used to save there text by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd>. This is done through the jQuery Hotkeys Plugin.

Since CKeditor puts its text editor within an iframe the shortcut does not work when editing text.

I hope someone can help me find a solution.

Answer (score 14):

After a morning struggling with it, I finally found the way to do that!

CKeditor already offers a hotkey functionality (see the [CKeditor documentation](http://docs.cksource.com/ckeditor_api/symbols/CKEDITOR.config.html#.keystrokes)). Using this functionality we can bind keystrokes to CKeditor actions. In order to save, the following line should be added:

```
[ CKEDITOR.CTRL + 83 /*S*/, 'save' ],
```

**However**, this will fire the default CKeditor save command. In my case I need to execute a JS function that sends the CKeditor data along with other stuff via AJAX to the server and leaves the user in the same form (doesn't exit).

After looking at the [CKeditor support forums](http://cksource.com/forums/viewtopic.php?p=42913#p42913) and after some coding, I arrived to the following solution (I use jQuery):

```
var isCtrl = false;

$('#your_textarea_id').ckeditor(function ()
{

    editor.on( 'contentDom', function( evt )
    {
        editor.document.on( 'keyup', function(event)
        {
            if(event.data.$.keyCode == 17) isCtrl=false;
        });

        editor.document.on( 'keydown', function(event)
        {
            if(event.data.$.keyCode == 17) isCtrl=true;
            if(event.data.$.keyCode == 83 && isCtrl == true)
            {
                //The preventDefault() call prevents the browser's save popup to appear.
                //The try statement fixes a weird IE error.
                try {
                    event.data.$.preventDefault();
                } catch(err) {}

                //Call to your save function

                return false;
            }
        });

    }, editor.element.$);
});
```

Tested in Firefox, Chrome and IE8.

Comment: Seems to work in CKEditor 4. Thanks a lot! Fwiw, I think you can remove the `isCtrl` overhead if you change the `83` check to `if (event.data.$.keyCode === 83 && event.data.$.ctrlKey) {`.

Answer (score 11):

It is possible to add custom commands to the editor and bind these commands to keystroke.
Here is an example (using jQuery adapter)

```
$(function() {
    // Create editor
    $('#textbox').ckeditor(function() {
            // Once the editor is loaded, we can add custom commands

            /** Alt + A will alert a greeting message **/
            // First, we define our custom command
            this.addCommand('myGreetingCommand', {
                exec : function(editor, data) {
                    alert("Hello world!");
                }
            });

            // Then, we set up the key combination
            this.keystrokeHandler.keystrokes[CKEDITOR.ALT + 65 /* A */] = 'myGreetingCommand';

            /** Ctrl + B will alert a good bye message **/
            this.addCommand('myGoodByeCommand', {
                exec : function(editor, data) {
                    alert("Goodbye!");
                }
            });

            this.keystrokeHandler.keystrokes[CKEDITOR.CTRL + 66 /* B */] = 'myGoodByeCommand';
        });

});
```