# CKEditor: How to disable keyboard shortcuts?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ckeditor, fckeditor

Does anyone know how to disable all keyboard shortcuts in CKEditor 3.4.1?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace the [`CKEditor.config.keystrokes`](http://docs.cksource.com/ckeditor_api/symbols/CKEDITOR.config.html#.keystrokes) with an empty array:

```
CKEDITOR.config.keystrokes = [];
```

See [`plugins_keystrokes_plugin.js`](http://docs.cksource.com/ckeditor_api/symbols/src/plugins_keystrokes_plugin.js.html), line 195.

Comment: By the way, is there any way if I want to disable keystrokes of a particular instance?

Comment: Oh. I got it. CKEDITOR.instances.textarea_id.config.keystrokes = [];

Answer (score 2):

You can do it this way:

```
var isCtrl = false;

$('#your_textarea_id').ckeditor(function ()
{

    editor.on( 'contentDom', function( evt )
    {
        editor.document.on( 'keyup', function(event)
        {
            if(event.data.$.keyCode == 17) isCtrl=false;
        });

        editor.document.on( 'keydown', function(event)
        {
            if(event.data.$.keyCode == 17) isCtrl=true;
            if(event.data.$.keyCode == 83 && isCtrl == true)
            {
                //The preventDefault() call prevents the browser's save popup to appear.
                //The try statement fixes a weird IE error.
                try {
                    event.data.$.preventDefault();
                } catch(err) {}

                //Call to your save function

                return false;
            }
        });

    }, editor.element.$);
});
```

Check out [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3245797/how-to-use-custom-keyboard-shortcuts-within-ckeditor-with-jquery) for more.

Comment: this has the same effect: `$('#your_textarea_id').ckeditor(function () { this.on('key', function (event) { if (event.data.keyCode == CKEDITOR.CTRL + 83) { event.cancel(); } }); });`