# How to disable copy or paste functionality on CKEditor 5 in reactJs?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-redux, ckeditor5

I'm working on a feature where **candidates can answer the questions**, but I don't want them to **copy and paste the answers from somewhere else to the CKEditor 5** which I have integrated **in my React Js** project.

I tried using text field onCopy and onPaste attributes, but it seems to be not working.
Is there any **prop** or **configuration** I can do to resolve this issue!

Thank you.

Comment: I haven't used CKEditor but I think you need to do two things. First, disable right click [context menu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2246631/how-to-disable-ckeditor-context-menu) so that text can't be copied or pasted using mouse. Second, you need to disable certain keys or [keyboard shortcuts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5217435/ckeditor-how-to-disable-keyboard-shortcuts) . I hope ckeditor has some kind of configs for these. You can follow the given links.

Comment: you can disable copy and paste through [here](https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/framework/guides/deep-dive/clipboard.html) to manipulate the clipboard data.

Comment: @Usama the links you have provided in your answers are for CK4 or older than CK4 versions which are not used in CK5,it is totally different and has new API which are not used in CK4 or previous versions.