# Open CKEditor with a keyboard shortcut

Tags: url, browser, ckeditor, keyboard-shortcuts

I use keyboard shortcuts within CKeditor all the time. One of the very useful ones is to save the page (and close the editor) with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>s</kbd>.
However, I just cannot find a keyboard shortcut to *open the editor*. I wouldn't be a CKEditor shortcut, but one of the browser. Does one exist?

If not, there still may be an alternative; In Mindtouch it is possible to open the editor on any page by adding the argument `action=edit` to the page URL. What tool could I use to create a keyboard shortcut that reloads the page with the argument added?

Comment: What do you mean by *open the editor*? I'm not quite sure what's your goal. You can create an editor on demand by calling `CKEDITOR.replace|appendTo|inline()` at any time. This has pretty much nothing to do with CKEDITOR. And there's nothing like a _"browser shortcut that opens editor"_. There are only document, listeners that listen on `keyup|keydown` events.

Answer (score 0):

I think shift + f10 should do it? Here is the full list of [keyboard shortcuts](http://docs.cksource.com/CKEditor_3.x/Users_Guide/Keyboard_Shortcuts)

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3245797/how-to-use-custom-keyboard-shortcuts-within-ckeditor-with-jquery) for an example of how to create your own key binding

Comment: nope, those shortcuts only apply when you have key focus on an open CKEditor window. When closed, shift-F10 simply opens the context menu of a webpage, since it is a valid browser shortcut aswell