# How can I add a keyboard shortcut for my command in CKEditor 3?

Tags: javascript, ckeditor, keyboard-shortcuts

My plugin defines a command to paste some data and generate a link from it.

Is there any way to make a keyboard shortcut for it? I can't find anything that works.

I cannot get [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3245797/how-to-use-custom-keyboard-shortcuts-within-ckeditor-with-jquery?rq=1) to work.

Running this from my plugin definition doesn't work either

```
CKEDITOR.config.keystrokes.append([CKEDITOR.CTRL + CKEDITOR.SHIFT + 108, 'pasteLotusLink']);
```

Nor trying to get at least bold to work from c-q:

```
editor.keystrokeHandler.keystrokes[CKEDITOR.CTRL + 113, 'bold'];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For 4.x, use [editor.setKeystroke](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.editor-method-setKeystroke):

```
CKEDITOR.plugins.add( 'foo', {
    init: function( editor ) {
        editor.setKeystroke( CKEDITOR.CTRL + 81, 'bold' ); // CTRL+Q
    }
} );
```

For 3.x:

```
CKEDITOR.plugins.add( 'foo', {
    init: function( editor ) {
        editor.on( 'instanceReady', function( evt ) {
            evt.removeListener();
            this.keystrokeHandler.keystrokes[ CKEDITOR.CTRL + 81 ] = 'bold'; // CTRL+Q
        } );
    }
} );
```

Comment: This does not work. Not surprising, considering the `Available since: `**`4.0`**