# CKEDITOR insert special symbol with Keyboard shortcut

Tags: ckeditor

I am working on a project which has a requirement is: if user press a shortcut then a symbol will insert in text editor. Like:

```
if press Shift+1 then insert ✓
if press Shift+2 then insert ✗
```

I have done this in textarea but I am using CKEDITOR in this project and I have tried by 'keystrokes' like this but didn't work:

```
CKEDITOR.config.keystrokes = [
        [ CKEDITOR.SHIFT + 76, function(){
            console.log('sdsd');
        } ]
];
```

Can somebody help me out please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use command to execute a function like follow.

```
CKEDITOR.plugins.add('foo',
    {            
        init: function( editor ) {
            editor.addCommand( 'sample', {
                exec: function( editor ) {
                    alert( 'Executing a command for the editor name "' + editor.name + '"!' );
                }
            } );

            editor.setKeystroke( CKEDITOR.CTRL + 81, 'sample' ); // CTRL+Q
        }
    });
```

or in your way but after defining the command.

```
CKEDITOR.config.keystrokes = [
        [ CKEDITOR.SHIFT + 76, 'sample' ]
];
```

The second value for the `CKEDITOR.config.keystrokes` expects a **command name** not a function.

**NB:** As the implementation is using plugin. You also have to configure the editor to use the plugin using `extraPlugins` configuration

```
CKEDITOR.replace('editor', {
        extraPlugins : 'foo'
    });
```

As your need is simply to map a keystroke to a symbol. You can use [this](http://ckeditor.com/addon/easykeymap) plugin.

**disclaimer:** I'm the author of [that](http://ckeditor.com/addon/easykeymap) plugin

Comment: Exactly what I am looking for, Thank you very much.

Comment: Is there a way to pass the key pressed into the function called as well in case I want multiple keys to call the same function?

Comment: @sometimes24 you can do it using the [plugin](https://ckeditor.com/cke4/addon/easykeymap) provided in the answer. For example [see here](http://xiidea.github.io/ckeditor-easykeymap-plugin/#ck-editor-easykeymap-demo)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use setkystroke method like this :

For 4.x, use editor.setKeystroke:

```
            CKEDITOR.plugins.add( 'test', {
                init: function( editor ) {
                    editor.setKeystroke( CKEDITOR.CTRL + 81, 'bold' ); // CTRL+Q
                }
            } );
```

For 3.x:

```
            CKEDITOR.plugins.add( 'test', {
                init: function( editor ) {
                    editor.on( 'instanceReady', function( evt ) {
                        evt.removeListener();
                        this.keystrokeHandler.keystrokes[ CKEDITOR.CTRL + 81 ] = 'bold'; // CTRL+Q
                    } );
                }
            } );
```

Comment: I saw this answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17706086/how-can-i-add-a-keyboard-shortcut-for-my-command-in-ckeditor-3 . but it didn't solve my problem

Comment: you need to use setKeystroke() method it's working well for me. I am using ckeditor version 4.x

Comment: Is there a way to pass the key pressed into the function called as well in case I want multiple keys to call the same function?