# Get original event object in CKEditor

Tags: jquery, ckeditor

#### The Context

I have a pretty simple use-case. My page has some configurable shortcut keys. I handle keydown events at the document node and, if the keypress is one of the configurable shortcuts, then I execute a series of actions and call `event.preventDefault()`, etc., to prevent standard actions from taking place (for example, overriding Ctrl/Cmd+S).

#### The Problem

CKEditor creates an iframe, making document-level event handling complicated. I found a very helpful post on SO that explained how to essentially inject custom document-level event handlers into the editor's iframe:
[How to use custom keyboard shortcuts within CKeditor with jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3245797/how-to-use-custom-keyboard-shortcuts-within-ckeditor-with-jquery)

Unfortunately, CKEditor is not passing along the original event object. After poking around in my dev console, I found a property that seemed to expose the original event object (`event.data.$`), but is actually a copy of the event object. For example, the `type` property is inherited, which confuses jQuery's `trigger()` function (it's calling `hasOwnProperty('type')` for some reason).

I can fix the jQuery issue by making a copy of the event object, but that changes the meaning of "this" which seems to screw up the `preventDefault()` function in the parent handler.

#### The Question

I need the *original* event object, one that I can call `preventDefault()` on and pass to jQuery's `trigger()` function without needing to manipulate anything. The parent document should handle processing keydown events and determine what action to take: it's not feasible to duplicate all the configurable shortcut code in the CKEditor contentDom handler.

#### The Example

Unfortunately, SO is much more restrictive about iframe manipulation than jsfiddle, so I've created both. You can check out the code in the snippet below, but you'll have to visit the jsfiddle to actually see this working:

http://jsfiddle.net/cyborgx37/swywgb7g/

```
var doc = $(document).on('keydown',function(e){
        if (e.keyCode === 83){
            e.preventDefault();
        }
    });

CKEDITOR.replace( 'foobar', {
        on : {
            contentDom : function() {
                this.document.on( 'keydown',
                    function(e){
                        var originalEvent = e.data.$;
                        
                        console.log({
                            type: originalEvent.type,
                            hasOwnResult: originalEvent.hasOwnProperty('type')
                        });
                        // type is "keydown" (type is defined!)
                        // but type is an inherited property so
                        // jQuery .trigger() ignores it and attempts
                        // to process the event as a string
                        
                        doc.trigger( 'keydown', originalEvent );
                        // doesn't have desired effect, because the original
                        // event (with keyCode) has been replaced by a generic
                        // event object (without keyCode)
                        
                        doc.trigger(e.data.$);
                        // causes error, because jQuery thinks that I've sent
                        // in a event name string rather than an event object
                        
                        doc.trigger($.extend({},e.data.$));
                        // causes error, "this" is no longer the original event
                        // resulting in an "illegal invocation" exception
                    }
                );
            }
        }
    }
);
```

```js
var doc = $(document).on('keydown',function(e){
        if (e.keyCode === 83){
            e.preventDefault();
        }
    });

CKEDITOR.replace( 'foobar', {
        on : {
            contentDom : function() {
                this.document.on( 'keydown',
                    function(e){
                        var originalEvent = e.data.$;
                        
                        console.log({
                            type: originalEvent.type,
                            hasOwnResult: originalEvent.hasOwnProperty('type')
                        });
                        // type is "keydown" (type is defined!)
                        // but type is an inherited property so
                        // jQuery .trigger() ignores it and attempts
                        // to process the event as a string
                        
                        doc.trigger( 'keydown', originalEvent );
                        // doesn't have desired effect, because the original
                        // event (with keyCode) has been replaced by a generic
                        // event object (without keyCode)
                        
                        doc.trigger(e.data.$);
                        // causes error, because jQuery thinks that I've sent
                        // in a event name string rather than an event object
                        
                        doc.trigger($.extend({},e.data.$));
                        // causes error, "this" is no longer the original event
                        // resulting in an "illegal invocation" exception
                    }
                );
            }
        }
    }
);
```

```css
#debug{
    font-family: monospace;
    color: red;
    margin: 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdn.ckeditor.com/4.4.7/standard/ckeditor.js"></script>

<h1>Typing "s" should be prevented, since we are calling "preventDefault()" if the keyCode is 83.</h1>
<h2>Works fine when typing in an input (you can't type an "s").</h2>
<input type="text">
<h2>Breaks for CKEditor, because we either can't pass along the original event, or jQuery breaks because, for some reason, jQuery cares whether or not type is an inherited property.</h2>
<textarea id="foobar"></textarea>
<h2>Error message (when attempting to use .trigger with the "original" (or as close as I can find in CKEditor) event object):</h2>
```

Comment: How about something like http://jsfiddle.net/dhirajbodicherla/swywgb7g/5/ ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer. Turns out that CKEditor implements its own (somewhat wonky, in my opinion) event system. The `editor.document` I was using was not a jQuery object, but a CKEditor object.

The fix turned out to be very simple:

```
var doc = $(document).on('keydown',function(e){
    if (e.keyCode === 83){
        e.preventDefault();
    }
});

CKEDITOR.replace( 'foobar', {
        on : {
            contentDom : function() {

                // Get the low-level DOM element and
                // wrap it in a jQuery object, then call .on()
                $(this.document.$).on( 'keydown',
                    function(e){

                        // now I've got a jQuery event, which
                        // trigger() is much happier with
                        doc.trigger(e);
                    }
                );
            }
        }
    }
);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/cyborgx37/e2t56dht/